# Sharing using ng2 share buttons in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have implented sharing functionality in my angular 2 project using ng2 Share buttons pluggin and it is working properly excpet one thing i.e, after the feed is shared and some user clicks on that shared feed he gets redirected to the the link I shared but I want him to land up on my websites login page for authentication purpose?

Here is my HTML code:-

```
          <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
            <div class="flipper">
              <div class="front">
                  <img  class="like_2" alt="image" (click) = "shareIt(i)" src="assets/img/Fwd Icons/share.png">
              </div>
              <div class="back">
                              <div class="row" >
                      <section class="widget sharing_buttons_widget">
                            <share-buttons  (click) = "closeShareIt(i)" [url]=" myFeed.contentUrl "
                                [count]="false"
                                [totalCount]="true"
                                [defaultStyle]= "true"
                                (popUpClosed) = "true"
                                [google]="googleInner"
                                [pinterest]="false"
                                [linkedIn]="false"
                                [tumblr]="tumblrInner"
                                [reddit]="false"
                                [stumbleUpOn]="false">
                          </share-buttons>                
                      </section>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

and in my component file:-

```
   hideFeed(myFeed){
      const FeedStar = {
      'FeedUId' : myFeed.uid
      };
       this.feedService.DynamicArticles(FeedStar).subscribe(
       data => {

          });  

          this.iframeURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(       myFeed.contentUrl);
          this.showIframe = true;        


    }
```

Comment: Is there any where you can add `callback-url` ? That is probably the thing you would require. May I also know which ng2share component are using?

Comment: you can add the call back method inside the subscribe method and this is the link for ng2 Share button https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ng2-sharebuttons

Comment: Is there a logic to use tokens i.e, if the the token is null the user will be redirected to the login page or something like that.

Comment: so basically you want them to login in beofre they can share is it?

Comment: Only provision to specify the URL is the one I added [url] = myFeed.contentUrl and I am getting this url from the API.

Comment: No the person alredy logged in will be able to share the feed but after the feed is shared some other user if wants to see whats inside he will be asked to login when he clicks on the shared feed.

Comment: You want to basically protect your article, why not use `can-authenticate` of angular2 that basically will redirect to login page if the user is not logged in.

Comment: So if the user is the one who shared or the one who didint! Doesnt matter, to read - log - in. SIMPLE!

Comment: I am not sure how to use it?

Comment: Okay! I will put the answer!

Comment: Yes exactly to read the article you need to login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, first of all, the question is wrong. You need to authenthicate the article. In order to use that you need to use `can Activate` property of `angular2`

In your routing module:

```
import { LoginService } from './login/login.service'
import { article } from './helpers/result/article.component'

const routes: Routes = 
[
{ path: 'article/:id', canActivate:[LoginService], component:article}
];
```

Explanation: article is the component you want to protect. LoginService the service that will return true if the user is logged in if not false.

Below is the snippet of login service.

```
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
@Injectable()
export class LoginService implements CanActivate {
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {

if(user.loggedIn) 
{
return true;
}
else
{
this._router.navigate(['/login']);
return false
}
}
}
```

Explanation: the canActivate method is extended from the class canActivate. This method where your logic falls. You can check if the user is logged in return true... then user can see the article, if you return false, it will navigate to login. You **cant** just return false without navigate. because in that case the user will stay on that page.

Ref: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html
You may wish to read the above reference to understand better and may be implement in a different logical manner. This is static approach i have been using for my application. There might be more.

PS: Please let me know if i am doing in a wrong manner. Comments are welcomed.